# Pattern Matching in cron

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to `grep` line which begin with `#` or `#*` or `number` or `#number`. In other word, I want to `grep`ing from the beginning of cron command until end of line. I don't need crontab header.
Here is crontab file :

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )

#*/56 * * * * root bash /media/data/minutely.sh 
#20 * * * * root bash /media/data/hourly.sh 
#* * * * * root bash /media/data/looping.sh
* * * * * root bash /media/data/looping2.sh
20 * * * * root bash /media/data/hourly2.sh
```

And what I want is :

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )

#*/56 * * * * root bash /media/data/minutely.sh 
#20 * * * * root bash /media/data/hourly.sh 
#* * * * * root bash /media/data/looping.sh
* * * * * root bash /media/data/looping2.sh
20 * * * * root bash /media/data/hourly2.sh
.
.
.
.
#until end of line
```

I have try with :

```
cat /etc/crontab | grep '^[^#0-9]'
```

But it give me output :

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

How can grep only pattern that I have explain above?
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Use instead `^[#0-9]`

Comment: Sorry sir, I have try it but the output still give me header (from `# /etc/crontab` until `# that none of the other crontabs do.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another sed variant that starts printing at the first line that begins with a digit:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]/,$p' /etc/crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sed:

```
sed -n '6,${/^[0-9#]/p}' /etc/crontab
```

`-n` option prevents to display lines automatically

`6,$` is a range of lines (from line 6 to the last line)

`/^[0-9#]/` tests if the line begin with `#` or a digit. If the test succeeds, `p` print the line.